# R Fast nested list iteration

Tags: r, lapply, nested-lists, mapply

I have an extremely long nested list of size several million. Here are the first few entries:

```
d1  
[[1]]  
   x Freq  
1 NA    4

[[2]]  
   x          Freq  
1  0005073936    8  
2          NA    4  

[[3]]  
   x          Freq  
1  0005073936   14
```

I want to populate the vector "s_week" with maximum frequency ("Freq") values from this list. For instance, in the above case, the answer will be

```
s_week=["NA","0005073936","0005073936"]
```

Here's my attempt to populate this vector iteratively.

```
for(i in 1:length(d1)){
s_week[i]=as.character(d1[[i]]$x[which(d1[[i]]$Freq==max(d1[[i]]$Freq))][1])
}
```

However, this is excruciatingly slow and takes forever as the list has more than 100 million entries. I was wondering if there's a more elegant non-iterative solution using lapply or its variants?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Can you provide `dput` of your data, at least few thousand rows?

Comment: this will probably be faster - `s_week <- sapply(d1, function(item) item$x[which.max(item$Freq)])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
unlist(lapply(d1, function(x) x[["x"]][which.max(x[["Freq"]])]))
```

As @jay.sf suggests, you may also rather use `$` instead of `[[`:

```
unlist(lapply(d1, function(x) x$x[which.max(x$Freq)]))
```

Comment: `unlist(lapply(...))` ==> `sapply(...)`

Comment: I've seen few times the first one being faster, but tbh don't think really significantly, so yeah - but I'll let @ahly or someone else put that in an answer

Comment: Thanks, these are all great. I am currently trying the one based on data.table that you had earlier, as I have found data.table to be faster in general. Not sure which of these various options is the fastest.

Comment: For many list elements with few rows, `lapply` (or `sapply`) may be the fastest. Otherwise - and if you're doing more complex operations -, `data.table` approach I've posted at the beginning could be worth trying. Let us know if it proves to be faster and I'll include it again.

Comment: @arg0naut91 I've also seen `lapply` to be faster than `sapply`, but it turned out stunningly differently, see benchmark in my answer. It also suggests to use `$` rather than `[[` extraction in your solution.

Comment: @jay.sf, thanks for flagging - I've edited my answer. I hope the OP comes back and actually evaluates on his list. I believe this is highly volatile depending on the actual complexity of data frames etc.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it is also highly important whether we use the `$` operator for the extraction or the `[[` brackets. Otherwise the solution might actually be slower than a `for` loop. `vapply` is also worth a try, it's similar to `sapply`, but has a pre-specified type of return value (in our case `character(1)`) and, thus, might be faster.

```
vapply(H, function(item) item$x[which.max(item$Freq)], FUN.VALUE=character(1))
```

I did a benchmark for you. List `H` has length `1e5`, entries have an average of `2.00` rows with SD `0.58`, column `x` contains `NA` at random. I hope I got it more or less right.

```
H[3:5]
# [[1]]
#      x Freq
# 1 <NA>   15
# 2 <NA>    7
# 
# [[2]]
#            x Freq
# 1       <NA>    8
# 2       <NA>    7
# 3 0000765808   14
# 
# [[3]]
#            x Freq
# 1       <NA>    9
# 2 0000618128    9
# 3       <NA>    5

sapply(H[[3]], class)
#           x        Freq 
# "character"   "numeric"
```

***Benchmark***

```
s_week <- NA
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  vapply=s_week <- vapply(H, function(item) item$x[which.max(item$Freq)],
                          FUN.VALUE=character(1)),
  sapply=s_week <- sapply(H, function(item) item$x[which.max(item$Freq)]),
  lapply2=s_week <- unlist(lapply(H, function(x) x$x[which.max(x$Freq)])),
  forloop={for(i in 1:length(H)) {
    s_week[i]=as.character(H[[i]]$x[which(H[[i]]$Freq == max(H[[i]]$Freq))][1])
  }},
  vapply2=s_week <- vapply(H, function(item) item[["x"]][which.max(item[["Freq"]])],
                           FUN.VALUE=character(1)),
  lapply=s_week <- unlist(lapply(H, function(item) item[["x"]][which.max(item[["Freq"]])])),
  sapply2=s_week <- sapply(H, function(item) item[["x"]][which.max(item[["Freq"]])]),
  times=20L)
# Unit: milliseconds
#    expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
#  vapply  508.1789  525.1708  589.4401  550.5763  577.3948  956.8675    20 a  
#  sapply  526.0700  552.1580  651.5795  586.8449  631.1057 1038.6949    20 a  
# lapply2  528.9962  564.0170  594.9651  590.1182  618.8509  715.0774    20 a  
# forloop  820.0938  890.6525 1004.3736  912.5017 1048.2990 1449.8975    20  b 
# vapply2 1694.4961 1787.8798 2028.4530 1863.9924 1919.8244 3349.9039    20   c
#  lapply 1700.2831 1851.8868 2102.6394 1938.5132 2161.0250 2964.7155    20   c
# sapply2 1752.4071 1883.6729 2069.3157 1971.4675 2074.1322 3216.9192    20   c
```

<sup>*Note:* Performed on a AMD FX(tm)-8350 Eight-Core Processor.</sup>

As it turns out, `vapply` with `$` seems to be fastest. The `for` loop seems actually still to be faster than the `lapply` with `[[` method for extraction.

I've taken `data.table::rbindlist` out of the benchmark since it performed unexpectedly slow. There might not really be an advantage since we don't have `data.table` objects yet. (Or probably the code is somewhat flawed? I'm not too familiar with `data.table`. It seems that also some `system` process is permanently involved.)

```
library(data.table)
system.time(
  s_week <- rbindlist(H, idcol=TRUE)[, .SD[which.max(Freq)], by=.id][, x]
  )
#  user  system elapsed 
# 41.26   15.93   35.44
```

I also found a `tidyverse` solution in the revision history that performed very slow and therefore also didn't make it into my benchmark.

```
library(tidyverse)
system.time(
  s_week <- map(H, ~ .x %>% slice(which.max(Freq)) %>% pull(x)) %>% unlist
  )
#  user  system elapsed 
# 70.59    0.18   72.12
```

***Data***

```
set.seed(42)
H <- replicate(1e5, {
  n <- sample(1:3, 1, replace=TRUE)
  data.frame(x=sprintf("%010d", sample(9:1e6, n)), 
             Freq=round(abs(rnorm(n, 6.2, 5)) + 1), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
}, simplify=FALSE)
# create NA's
H <- lapply(H, function(x) {
  s <- sample(1:nrow(x), sample(1:nrow(x), 1), replace=FALSE)
  if (length(s) != 0)
    x[s, 1] <- NA
  else
    x
  return(x)
})
```

Comment: Interesting benchmark! However, for `vapply` I'm not sure it's gonna work as OP has `NA`s in there & column types may differ. It'd be essential to get a good `dput`.

Comment: @arg0naut91 You've made a point, if *all* `x` in a list entry are `NA`, it causes an entire column to be rather `logical` than `character` and `vapply` will fail in such case.

Comment: @arg0naut91 No, wait, the guess was wrong, it won't fail. This is only true if an entire `Freq` column is `NA`. I've adapted test data and updated the benchmark.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much @jay.sf for benchmarking the results and pointing out the speef differences between $ vs [[ based versions.